# AFrame - exclude Entity from camera Fuse

Tags: javascript, aframe

does someone of you know a possibility to exclude Entities from the Camera Fuse???

I would like to use the Fuse cursor to trigger click events, but still i don't want the cursor to fuse on every single entity. 
I'm sure there is a possibility to do what I want... but I cant find my way there. o0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/cursor.html#configuring-the-cursor-through-the-raycaster-component

> The cursor builds on top of and depends on the raycaster component. If we want to customize the raycasting pieces of the cursor, we can do by changing the raycaster component properties. Say we want set a max distance, check for intersections less frequently, and set which objects are clickable:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/raycaster.html#whitelisting-entities-to-test-for-intersection

> To select or pick the entities we want to test for intersection, we can use the objects property. If this property is not defined, then the raycaster will test every object in the scene for intersection. objects takes a query selector value:

```
<a-cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable"></a-cursor>
<a-box class="clickable"></a-box>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Tanx a lot. This was what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

just for people to know... if you use raycaster and curser in a entity you need to set the raycaster before the curser:

`<a-entity raycaster="objects: .clickable" cursor>`  WORKS!

`<a-entity cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable">`  DONT!

Comment: Thanks, this should be fixed in 0.4.0.